# T4 template for generating entity code without any config

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, t4

With the entity framework 4.1, it is now possible to use code first:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

However, this still requires a config file with a model.

Is there T4 template for generating DB access code in C# exclusively, no config file, no edmx file?

In particular, this T4 template should generate the OnModelCreating method.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes such tool exists. It's part of [EF Power tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) (currently in CTP1) and it is called Reverse Engineer code first. It is not T4 template and it still generates connection string into config file but whole mapping is generated in the code (no edmx).

Comment: If you have some issue with the tool don't forget to mention it at least as the comment in the article. It is still preview version so issues can be solved before final release.